# Javafx Canvas rect does not draw

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

i do something very basical and i just can't figure out what went wrong.

i try to draw a grid on a canvas, which seems straight forward, but i have problems with the outline of my rectangles. They simply are not drawn!!

```
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setLineWidth(2d);

    for (int dy = 0; dy < height; dy ++){
        for (int dx = 0; dx < width; dx ++){
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(new Color( random.nextDouble(), random.nextDouble(), random.nextDouble() ,1));
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(dx*32,dy*32,32,32);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().rect(dx*32,dy*32,32,32);
        }
    }
```

the result is quite funny since it DOES draw, but not the outline...

[image]

can't be that hard, can it? what am i missing?

Comment: i hope i did not do something very emberrasing, something total obvious...

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just append elements to the path, but you never do anything with it. You need to invoke some method using the path. In your case you need to call `stroke`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(512, 512);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(canvas));

    Random random = new Random();
    final int height = 16;
    final int width = 16;

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    gc.setLineWidth(2d);

    for (int dy = 0; dy < height; dy++) {
        for (int dx = 0; dx < width; dx++) {
            gc.setFill(new Color(random.nextDouble(), random.nextDouble(), random.nextDouble(), 1));
            gc.fillRect(dx * 32, dy * 32, 32, 32);
            gc.rect(dx * 32, dy * 32, 32, 32);
        }
    }

    // draw the path we've constructed during the loop
    gc.stroke();

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I'm out of office, I'll try it out tomorrow morning (timezone Europe) +1 for the very convincing explanation!

Comment: And thanks for adding the code for a minimal running example...

Comment: that's it - just **ONE LINE CODE** (`canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().stroke();`) was missing - i am standing deeply in your debt!! thank you very very much